# How to pull/read data from an external SQL server in batches ard store all in one kdb+ table

Tags: sql, postgresql, odbc, kdb

We have an external PostgreSQL server where we pull data from using odbc. We typically pull data in chunks as we need, so sometimes pull all date "where date > (some specific date)" or "where id > (some specified id)" or between certain dates (like start_date and end_date). Example code below

The above conditions are pretty straight forward and can be implemented without burdening the server too much.

But it's a different story when we need to pull the entire server data (too much data on the server). Is there a way to pull data from the server in batches so an to not overburden the server?

Below is an example that we use to

```
getdata:{[]
 query: "select data.id, data.first_name, data.last_name, data.email, data.created_at from data  where data.created_at > '2020-02-04' order by id asc" ];
 us::.odbc.open `dbs;
 leads::.odbc.eval[us; query];
 .odbc.close us;
 };
```

dbs = server name

Comment: Sure. Track the last date/id you pulled, then iterate using your existing procedures providing the last value as the starting point. BTW there is no point in sorting on the data extraction, when inserted the ordering will be ignored.

Comment: @Belayer No, the ordering will not be ignored, kdb preserves the ordering during insert or select

Comment: Sorry, looks I misread. I thought you were inserting in Postgres, which would ignore ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you create date batches on the kdb side and generate a startDate-endDate query for each? e.g. create 5 years of start/end dates starting at 2002.01.01

```
q){(`date$s),'-1+`date$12+s:(12*til y)+`month$x}[2002.01.01;5]
2002.01.01 2002.12.31
2003.01.01 2003.12.31
2004.01.01 2004.12.31
2005.01.01 2005.12.31
2006.01.01 2006.12.31
```

I guess you would have to loop over each table on the server also.